# Annotations not showing on colormap using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, colorbar

I am trying to create a heatmap for my Needleman-Wunsch Algorithm, however, I can't seem to label the individual cells of the figure. The figure is pretty much how I'd like it to be, however, I am just missing the individual values in the cells. I have followed the documentation and examples for matplotlib, however, I cant seem to find the error, I'm sure it's simple but I just can't seem to spot it.

```
dna1 = [c for c in "CAAAGACCTGAAGAGCCAGTGGACTCCACCCCACTTTCTGGTCTGACCAATAT"]
dna2 = [c for c in "ACCACACTCTCTGGGCTGACCAATTACAGCGCTTCTACAGAACTGAAGACTCAC"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))
im = ax.imshow(raw_data, aspect='auto')

# We want to show all ticks...
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(dna1)))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(dna2)))
# ... and label them with the respective list entries
ax.set_xticklabels(dna1)
ax.set_yticklabels(dna2)

# Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")

# Gridlines based on minor ticks
plt.pcolormesh(raw_data, edgecolors='k', linewidth=1)

# Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.

for i in range(len(dna1)):
    for j in range(len(dna2)):
        try:
            ax.text(i, j, raw_data[i, j], ha="center", va="center", color="w", fontsize = 15)
        except KeyError:
            continue
        

ax.set_title("")
plt.show()
```

Outputs the below:

[image: Output]

Example of the raw_data:

[image: ex2]

Comment: Can you please share an example of `raw_data`?

Comment: @ZeroPancakes Ive added a screenshot of the .txt file of the raw_data

Answer (score 0):

Running the following code

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))

Z = np.random.rand(6, 10)
x = np.arange(0.5, 11, 1)
y = np.arange(0.5, 7, 1)

plt.pcolormesh(x,y,Z, edgecolors='k', linewidth=1)

# Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(6):
        ax.text(i+1, j+1, "lol", ha="center", va="center", color="b", fontsize = 50)
plt.show()
```

We get the output

[image: lol8]

Have you tried removing the line `im = ax.imshow(raw_data, aspect='auto')` ?

Comment: I have yeah, it produces a slightly better output but theres still no annotations to the cells on the figure, its still blank. Is the for loop I have above correct?

Comment: @lambda Then the problem seems likely to be either in the output format/zoom or in the `for` loop. What data type is `raw_data`? `np.array` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
dna1 = [c for c in "CAAAGACCTGAAGAGCCAGTGGACTCCACCCCACTTTCTGGTCTGACCAATAT"]
dna2 = [c for c in "ACCACACTCTCTGGGCTGACCAATTACAGCGCTTCTACAGAACTGAAGACTCAC"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,20))

# dummy data:
raw_data = np.random.randint(0,10,(len(dna2),len(dna1)))

# you just need the colormesh, and can dispense with the imshow.
# (using both leads to the overlapping images in your question)
plt.pcolormesh(raw_data, edgecolors='k', linewidth=1)

# We want to show all ticks... 
# ... and shift them by 0.5 to avoid ambiguity
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0.5, len(dna1)))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0.5, len(dna2)))
# ... and label them with the respective list entries
ax.set_xticklabels(dna1)
ax.set_yticklabels(dna2)

# Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")

# Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.

for i in range(len(dna1)):
    for j in range(len(dna2)):
        try: # i switched the raw_data indices
            ax.text(i+.5, j+.5, raw_data[j, i], ha="center", va="center", color="w", fontsize = 15)
        except:
            continue
        

ax.set_title("")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I see how this is correct, however I've made the changes you've suggested, but for some reason its still not appearing for me, I don't understand what could be the issue

Comment: @lambda can you add a lint with a print statement after the `except:` line? Such as `print(f'{i}, {j}')`

Comment: Ive added a lint output, it just iterates through the 0,1.... 55,1...,55,55. I think the issue is the 0,0 field? For some reason it gives a KeyError that ive ignored using the exception line, im not sure if thats the issue though @warped

Comment: I should add, my data is a 55 x 54 matrix

Comment: If you copy+paste all the code in my answer, and execute it, does it give the image that I posted?

Comment: Yeah it comes out identically, I still havent managed to get the annotations to show on mine

Comment: @lambda I tried both a matrix and an array and it works with both. Run `print(type(raw_data))`

Comment: @ZeroPancakes Its a Numpy Array, the output gives <class 'numpy.ndarray'> so im honestly unsure

Comment: @lambda have you tried copy+pasting my code, but with your raw_data?